# dealing with path in Eclipse and maven

Tags: spring, maven, spring-test, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a multi module maven project (ModuleA, ModuleB, ModuleC)

I have a test in ModuleA

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = 
           { "file:../ModuleB/src/test/resources/application-context-test.xml",
             "classpath:/mvc-dispatcher-servlet-test.xml"
           })
```

that load context from a file in ModuleB.

When I run the test in eclipse it works. But not when test are run by maven.

In eclipse the currentpath is set to ModuleA but in maven it is set in the parent folder.

so I should write :

> file:**.**/ModuleB/src/test/resources/application-context-test.xml

insead of

> file:**..**/ModuleB/src/test/resources/application-context-test.xml

to make it works in maven (but it would break eclipse)

thanks !

How can I tell maven (or surefire plugin) to run unit test relative to the module path and not the parent ?

Comment: Why not to use `classpath` instead of `file`?

Comment: I tried : "classpath:/application-context-test.xml" but it seems that this file is not in the classpath. Maybe if I move it from to ModuleB/src/main/resources/ it will be in the classpath...

Comment: Aggh... Missed that it is located in test folder.

Comment: Anyway it *is not very good idea* to have tests that depend of another module tests.

Answer (score 1):

Files placed in `${project.basedir}/src/test/resources` are copied to `${project.build.testOutputDirectory}`, which is 'target/test-classes' by default.  Maven does this automatically as part of the `generate-testResources` phase.

Thus, you do not want to look for the file in the /src/test/resources directory, as that is not on the classpath.  If you had a test in ModuleB looking for the file, you would write it like this:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = 
       { "classpath:/application-context-test.xml",
         "classpath:/mvc-dispatcher-servlet-test.xml"
       })
```

The difficulty you are running into is that the file you want exists in another project.  So the problem you are trying to solve is, how do I get the resource from the other project onto this project's classpath?  You may do one of two things to address this:

One: Execute the [maven jar plugin's `test-jar` goal](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/test-jar-mojo.html) in ModuleB.  This will take all of the classes and resources in ModuleB's `target/test-classes` directory and package it into a jar.  Then, you may add the test jar as a dependency in Module A's POM like this:

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>com.mycompany.theGroupId</groupId>
     <artifactId>moduleB</artifactId>
     <version>yourVersion</version>
     <type>test-jar</type>
    <scope>test</scope>
 </dependency>
```

Two: You may move Module B's test resources into a separate project (in directory `newProject/src/main/resources`), let Maven build the jar as usual, and have both ModuleA and ModuleB add newProject as a dependency with scope `test`.

Answer (score 0):

Add this rather than a forward slash - `"classpath:application-context-test.xml"`

Maven will automatically pull it from resources

Comment: I didn't try in maven but in eclipse it can't find it, I need a solution that work in both

Answer (score 0):

No matter what sotution is, this is not best pratice.

Please do as following:

First, make sure if module A denpends module B? (I guess yes)

If yes, use `classpath:/application-context-test.xml` ,then, use mvn install under parent dir to package module B and install it. then, you can run you test cases, it should works.

If not, please copy application-context-test.xml into module A but I think this is strange. normally, if you want to use a file of other module, it's because this module depends it.

Comment: Yes copying the file is what I will be ending doing. But in last hope I did : update surefire plug in from 2.16 to 2.17 and remove the <forkCount>0</forkCount> to have the default value, and now it seems to works :|